# Need advice and solution

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
   <img id="back" />
   <img id="front" />
  </div>
  <div class="body">
   ...
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
   ...
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: -8px;
width: 1024px;
height: 1500px;
background-color: #CCC;
border: 1px solid;
/*display: run-in;*/
/*position:fixed;*/
text-align: center;
}

.header {
background-color: #FFC;
/*margin: 0 auto;*/
height: 150px;
width: 1000px;
display: box;
z-index: 10;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
position: fixed;
display:block;
}

#back {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

#front{
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
```

}

I need to have header fixed on top of page (wrapper is fixed width) with images inside of wrapper centered both horizontally and vertically inside of header. How to achieve that?

O.K.
To clarify
Wrapper is to be fixed width.
Header should stick on top of page (inside of wrapper) and contain two pictures/images. Images should overlap one another and be centered both vertically and horizontally inside header.
Hope I'm now precise enough.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: Have to say perhaps this question shouldn't be answered, if you improve your question i'll improve my answer

Comment: Sure, I'll improve question, no need to be like that.

Comment: why have you not posted any CSS whatsoever?? SO is not intended to have people write code for you, but rather to help with problems within your code. Nothing in your question can't be easily found in web search

Comment: Image dimensions? Header height? Any other CSS rules you're already using?

Comment: Here it is with css I've tried

Answer (score 0):

What about: [briefly more psudo code untested]

css:

```
.wrapper{
 width: 960px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.banding{
/*add stuff*/
}

.header{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 150px;
 margin-top: 40%; /*this will depend on images etc*/
}
```

then in html:

```
<div class="header banding">
       <img />
       <img />
   </div>
    <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="body">
       ...
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
       ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nope. header is on center of page, and is extending over 960px of wrapper. Header should stick on top of page inside of wrapper. I'll post soon what I've tried.

Comment: Sorry, my definition of a header is just that.

Comment: No problem, but I'm trying to achieve this...
How can I post a picture here for better understanding what I need?